# Flask, Get value from HTML

Tags: python, html, flask

Super simple question, I'm using flask and I want to get the string value of this array. I know how to use `request.fom["name"]`, but I cannot assign this variable a name. How would I get this variable to then put it on my next page?

```
{% for row in students %}
  <form action="{{ url_for('user') }}" method = "POST">
    <tr>
      {{ row[0] }} <br />
      <input type="submit">
      <p> </p> <br />
    </tr>
  </form>
{% endfor %}
```

I need the value of row[0], how would I assign a name to that, or just get the information?

Comment: You can't assign a name in a template, they're purely for presentation logic. But you can do it in your Flask backend (Python code) and then pass it to the template if needed.

Comment: What's wrong with `row[0]`?

Comment: I can't pass it to a new page.

Comment: Care to expand a bit on your last comment? Even using jinja's `{% set %}` (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#assignments) it would still not achieve the goal you're after. Using `set` is a good way of avoiding repetition of long statements such as `row[0].name` or whatever, and makes it more obvious. If you have to pass it to another page, calling it `user_data` or calling it `row[0].attribute` won't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment is expression and syntax for expressions in jinja follows `{% %}`. So this should work

```
{% set data = row[0] %}
```